# I would like to vlookup or Index Match, converting columns in arrays to make it faster

Tags: excel, vba

I have Page 1 and Page 2.
In Page 2 I would like to give a status that indicates if "Reference Number" is also found in Page1.
Vlook Up and Index Match is very very slow, can someone help me convert in arrays or somthing like that to make it hiper fast?

This is what I tried, but it is ver slow when you have over 6000 rows.

```
Sub Calculate()

Set Page1 = Worksheets("Page1")
Set Page2 = Worksheets("Page2")

LastRowPage1 = Page1.Cells(Page1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowPage2 = Page2.Cells(Page2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRowPage1
Page2.Range("E" & i) = Application.Match(Page2.Range("D" & i).Value, Page1.Columns(3), 0)

    If IsNumeric(Page2.Range("E" & i).Value) Then
        Page2.Range("E" & i) = "Yes"
        Else
        Page2.Range("E" & i) = "No"
End If
Next
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

I need it with vba because its a small part of a big process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another option. You mentioned converting the columns to arrays. That is a possibility and should be quite fast. If you get a chance to try it as well as the other answer you got, I'd be interested in the performance difference.

```vb
Sub Calculate()

Set page1 = Worksheets("Page1")
Set page2 = Worksheets("Page2")

lastrowpage1 = page1.Cells(page1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowpage2 = page2.Cells(page2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim lookupArr() As Variant, valueArr() As Variant, resultArr() As Variant, rng As Range
Set rng = page1.Range("C2:C" & lastrowpage1)
lookupArr = rng
Set rng = page2.Range("D2:D" & lastrowpage2)
valueArr = rng
ReDim resultArr(1 To UBound(valueArr), 1 To UBound(valueArr, 2))

For i = 1 To UBound(valueArr)
    resultArr(i, 1) = "no"
    For j = 1 To UBound(lookupArr)
        If valueArr(i, 1) = lookupArr(j, 1) Then
            resultArr(i, 1) = "yes"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Dim resultRng As Range
Set resultRng = page2.Range("E2:E" & lastrowpage2)
resultRng = resultArr

End Sub
```

Comment: yours is incredibly fast. 6047 lines in 3'87 seconds.
The one @ike gives takes over 15 minutes, and normally crashes.
Thank you both any ways!!

The Array Way is incredible, trying to learn that logic, thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is slow because you calculate each cell individually plus you are writing twice to each cell ... this is very slow.

Instead you can use formula to retrieve the result and then turn the result into values:

```vb
Sub Calculate()

Dim Page1 As Worksheet, Page2 As Worksheet

Set Page1 = Worksheets("Page1")
Set Page2 = Worksheets("Page2")

Dim lastRowPage1 As Long, lastRowPage2 As Long
lastRowPage1 = Page1.Cells(Page1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowPage2 = Page2.Cells(Page2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With Page2.Range("E2:E" & lastRowPage2)
    .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(MATCH(D2,Page1!C2:C" & lastRowPage1 & " ,0)),""no"",""yes"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I did some testing comparing your solution to mine. I used 50000 rows of random 3 letter combinations on both pages. The performance seems to be roughly the same (mine was 57.441 seconds, yours 64.931 seconds). What's strange though is that your solution failed to find some matches (I checked manually and the match definitely exists). No idea why.